# Print Character x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

So here is some of my code:

```
.data
    testString:
        .ascii "Test String\0"

.text
    .global _start

    .code16

    _start:
        movl testString, %si

        movb (%si), %al
        call printChar
        jmp _exit

    printChar:
        movb $0x0E, %ah
        movb $0x07, %bl
        int $0x10
        ret

    _exit:
        ...
```

What I am trying to do is move the pointer for the string into the si register so that I can print each character by using something like:

> > incw %si

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: You will need `movw $testString, %si` to load the address into `si`. I assume you know what you are doing with 16 bit code and bios interrupts and you are not trying to run this under a 32 bit os, such as linux.

Comment: Why movw? Doesnt movl move a 64 bit address?

Comment: `movl` is 32 bit, `movw` is 16 bit. `movq` would be 64 bit. You are writing 16 bit code (for whatever reason).

Comment: 16-bit code is being written because he isn't in real mode, since this is a boot program (as indicated by the fact he's executing `int 0x10`)